# Is there any way to retrieve webpage from local cache in Brave browser?

Tags: browser, cache, brave-browser

I viewed webpage on Brave browser that later was deleted. Is there any way to retrieve this webpage from local cache?

I know that there is soft like Nirsoft ChromeCacheView, but it can only extract files from cache on PC. I know, because I tried to use it on android cache of Brave browser (from folder `/data/data/com.brave.browser/Cache/cache`).

Comment: You can try to retrieve app data from a PC via USB (if the allows it) via `adb backup com.brave.browser` and then decrypt and unpack the created file via ABE (Android Backup Extractor). If the app denies backup you can only get the app data with root permissions. Unlocking and rooting a device deletes all data so if your device is not yet rooted this way is not an option.

Comment: AFAIK, cache is usually stored in the app's private folder. Accessing this folder needs root access.

Comment: Check if the webpage you are after was already archived on https://web.archive.org.

Comment: No archive of webpage anywhere, also `adb backup` not working. Looks like I will need to wait for some exploit for android or brave to get my files. Or to brave team to add something like view-cache.